# Calling a function which has inside async statements (should I use process.nextTick in parent ?)

Tags: node.js

Suppose I have the following code:

```
foo();

function foo() {
   func1("bla", function() {
                console.log("done!");
               });
}

function func1(value,callback) {
       process.nextTick(callback);
}
```

Will the function above will be totally async ?
Or should I use this foo function? :

```
function foo() {
    process.nextTick(function() { 
                          func1("bla", function() {
                          console.log("done!");
                     });
}
```

Actually my question is if the parent blocks the child process from being Async ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first option is going to be "async" in the sense that node might do other things before calling the callback method.

There is no need to call the second method. As soon as your foo function finishes and any parent callers of foo finish node will start doing other work, which eventually will be the work registered by nextTick.

Comment: So what you are actually saying is that the first option is ok to use, because "process.nextTick(callback)" will free the event-loop to do some other stuff. When the stack is empty, it would execute the callback. right ? (First option = the first foo() function I wrote)

Comment: yes. Just add a console.log statement to your foo() function before and after it calls func1 to test this.